# Collect links from web pages using thread pool java

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I am programming a links collector from specified number of pages. To make it more efficient I am using a ThreadPool with fixed size. Because I am really a newbie in the multithreading area I have problems with fixing some issues. So my idea is that every thread does the same thing: Connect to page and collect every url. After that urls are added to Queue for next thread.

But this doesn't work. At first program analyze baseurl and add urls from it. But at first I want to do it only with LinksToVisit.add(baseurl) and run it with threadpool but it always poll queue and threads add nothing new so on the top of queue is null.And I dont know why:(

I tried to do it with ArrayBlockingQueue but with no success. Fixing it with analyze base url is not good solution because when on baseurl is for example only one link it doesn't follow it. So I think I am going about it the wrong way or missing something important. As html parser I am using Jsoup. Thanks for answers.

Source(removed unnecessary methods) :

```
package collector;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class Collector {

private String baseurl;
private int links;
private int cvlinks;
private double time;
private int chcount;
private static final int NTHREADS = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()*2;
private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> LinksToVisit = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>();
private ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, Double> SortedCharMap = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, Double>();
private ConcurrentHashMap<String, Double> CharMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Double>();

public Collector(String url, int links) {
    this.baseurl = url;
    this.links = links;
    this.cvlinks = 0;
    this.chcount = 0;

    try {
        Document html = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        if(cvlinks != links){
            Elements collectedLinks = html.select("a[href]");
            for(Element link:collectedLinks){
                if(cvlinks == links) break;
                else{
                    String current = link.attr("abs:href");
                    if(!current.equals(url) && current.startsWith(baseurl)&& !current.contains("#")){
                        LinksToVisit.add(current);
                        cvlinks++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        AnalyzeDocument(html, url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    CollectFromWeb();
}

private void AnalyzeDocument(Document doc,String url){
    String text = doc.body().text().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", "").trim();
    chcount += text.length();
    String chars[] = text.split("");
    CharCount(chars);

}
private void CharCount(String[] chars) {
    for(int i = 1; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if(!CharMap.containsKey(chars[i]))  
            CharMap.put(chars[i],1.0);
        else
            CharMap.put(chars[i], CharMap.get(chars[i]).doubleValue()+1);
    }
}

private void CollectFromWeb(){
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREADS);
     CollectorThread[] workers = new CollectorThread[this.links];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.links; i++) {
        if(!LinksToVisit.isEmpty()){
            int j = i+1;
            System.out.println("Collecting from "+LinksToVisit.peek()+" ["+j+"/"+links+"]");
            //Runnable worker = new CollectorThread(LinksToVisit.poll());   
            workers[i] = new CollectorThread(LinksToVisit.poll());
            executor.execute(workers[i]);
        }
        else break;
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    while (!executor.isTerminated()) {}

    SortedCharMap.putAll(CharMap);

    this.time =(System.nanoTime() - startTime)*10E-10;
}

class CollectorThread implements Runnable{
    private Document html;
    private String url;

    public CollectorThread(String url){
        this.url = url;
        try {
            this.html = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(cvlinks != links){
            Elements collectedLinks = html.select("a[href]");
            for(Element link:collectedLinks){
                if(cvlinks == links) break;
                else{
                    String current = link.attr("abs:href");
                    if(!current.equals(url) && current.startsWith(baseurl)&& !current.contains("#")){
                        LinksToVisit.add(current);
                        cvlinks++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        AnalyzeDocument(html, url);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the LinksToVisit queue, just call `executor.execute(new CollectorThread(current))` directly from `CollectorThread.run()`. The `ExecutorService` has its own internal queue of tasks which it will run as threads become available.

The other problem here is that calling shutdown() after adding the first set of URLs to the queue will prevent new tasks from being added to the executor. You can fix this by instead making the executor shut down when it has emptied its queue:

```
class Queue extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
    Queue(int nThreads) {
        super(nThreads, nThreads, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 
                new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
    }

    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
        if(getQueue().isEmpty()) {
            shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seem that its working, but I dont know if I fully understand executor.execute(new CollectorThread(current)) calling inside CollectorThread.run(). I have to remove loop for creating workers right? It work somehow like recursive? thanks